# dygraphs not working as expected, version 1.1.0 does work, with Waterfox and Safari, but not version 2.1.0

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

The relevant generated html is...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="dygraph.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="graphdiv" style="height: 600px; width: 1100px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById('graphdiv'),

"Date Time,Humidity,Temperature,Dewpoint,Voltage\n" +
"2020-03-19 15:10:01,23,36.7,12.2,5.166\n"  +
"2020-03-19 15:11:01,22,36.9,11.7,5.19\n"  +
"2020-03-19 15:12:01,22,37,11.78,5.19\n"  +
"2020-03-19 15:13:01,22,37.09,11.86,5.19\n"  +
"2020-03-19 15:14:01,22,37.09,11.86,5.19\n"  +
etc.
"2020-03-22 19:16:01,41,28.7,14.16,5.166\n"  +
"2020-03-22 19:17:01,41,28.7,14.16,5.166\n"  +
"2020-03-22 19:18:02,42,28.6,14.45,5.19\n"  +
"2020-03-22 19:19:02,42,28.6,14.45,5.19\n" 

)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now with version 1.1.0, no worries, it displays, but some of the features of the newer version are obviously not available, if, however, I try and use 2.1.0 the browser complains about:
The script from “http://raspbx.local/dygraphs-2.1.0/dygraph-combined.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
barn.html

Loading failed for the  with source “http://raspbx.local/dygraphs-2.1.0/dygraph-combined.js”.

Then changing from dygraph-combined.js to dygraph.js it complains about:
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
dygraph.js:45

ReferenceError: Dygraph is not defined
barn.html:21:1

​Now researching this lot and not understanding it, I ended up changing a boatload of things, like making sure that every import line in all the various .js files include a "./" as part of the filename (where it was missing) to import as well as adding the ".js" suffix. Also changed in the html file

```
<script type="text/javascript"
```

to

```
<script type="module"
```

After all of this, I am now left with the error of:
ReferenceError: Dygraph is not defined
barn.html:11:1

Now, somewhere below all the imports and "use strict"; and some "var Dygraph=", there is:

Dygraph.NAME = "Dygraph";

Dygraph.VERSION = "2.1.0";

which, with my, by now, seriously limited knowledge, I would assume should be read as the definition and name of the .js module which should get loaded by the .html file, but now I'm down to my last 3 strands of hair and know no further... HELP! if you can edumacate me... now, I'm guessing I am doing something daft and boneheaded, but for the life of me, I need someone with more knowledge to point this out to me, please.

Comment: Where did you get your `dygraph-combined.js` file? The files [listed for download](http://dygraphs.com/download.html) do not include that. If you `dygraph.js` or `dygraph.min.js` form that page, you shouldn't get a module error.

Comment: I originally downloaded the .zip from github and that's also where the older version came from, under releases I grabbed v1.1.0, which is working and displaying graphs, after I didn't get anywhere with v2.1.0. The dygraph-combined.js file is in the v1.1.0 .zip.

Comment: What confuses me is that your example references `dygraphs-2.1.0/dygraph-combined.js`, but there's no such thing. Is the version in that URL inaccurate? Do you get an error when you use `dygraph.js` from the 2.1.0 release on the [downloads page](http://dygraphs.com/download.html)? (Generally npm is a better place to download files than GitHub releases.)

Comment: Oops, I guess I made a typo/didn't maybe make it 100% clear, yes, in version 2.1.0, it is dygraph.js, that I have to panel beat due to the "import declarations may only appear at top level of a module" errors etc. and eventually still end up with "ReferenceError: Dygraph is not defined barn.html:11:1" after everything. There is *no* dygraph-combined.js in version 2.1.0, but there is and it is what I can use in version 1.1.0.

Comment: Grab `dygraph.js` for 2.1.0 from the downloads page and you should be good to go. That's the version for distribution and it does not include any import statements.

Comment: Thanks, I just did as you suggested and now it does work, since all the imports are gone...
Question, why is this version different from the one on Github, but don't worry, either way, it is working. Now to figure out how to set all the other options etc.

Thanks to you Dan, I got the end results of environmental data collected in a mariadb table looking spiffy on some graphs.

Comment: I summarized this exchange into an answer. GitHub releases usually aren't a good way to download software. They typically just contain the source code, rather than the compiled/bundled/minified code that you want for use on your web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comment thread on the question for more details, but it turned out that the `dygraphs-2.1.0/dygraph-combined.js` file referenced was actually `dygraph.js` from the a zip file on the [GitHub Releases page](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/releases) for dygraphs.

This is *not* the correct way to get dygraphs. Instead, follow the instructions on the [dygraphs download page](http://dygraphs.com/download.html) to get bundled files for distribution. That page has links to the same files hosted on cdnjs and for download via npm.